# Python - Py2exe error

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

## **Problem:**

i cant use py2exe in a .exe file. I can only use it in a .py files instead
when i execute it in a shell window it works, but when i compile the app, it does not work.

## here is the code i am using:

```
  print "importing..."
  import wx
  import py2exe
  import sys
  import os
  from distutils.core import setup
  sys.argv.append('py2exe')
  print "done"

  class Frame(wx.Frame):
      def OnClick0(self, event):
          print "building application..."
          setup(
            windows = (['windows.py']),

            )

def __init__(self, parent, ID, title, pos=wx.DefaultPositin, size=((640,480)), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent, ID, title, pos, size, style)
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    button = wx.Button(panel, label="Install")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick0, button)

  def main():
      app = wx.App();
      frame = Frame(None, -1, 'Python Compressor Minimal');
      frame.Show()
      app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

## ErrorCode

```
 error: invalid command 'bdist'
```